# Name of some specific orders in number fields

Tags: terminology, algebraic-number-theory

Let  $\mathbb{K}/\mathbb{Q}$  a number field.

For an integer $\theta\in\mathfrak{o}_\mathbb{K}$, one can define an order 
$$
\mathbb{Z}[\theta] = \oplus_i \mathbb{Z} \theta^i.
$$

Is there a canonical naming for this kind of orders?

*Monogeneous orders? Principal orders*, like for ideals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer algebra system `magma` calls such a thing an *equation order*.

It is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$, where $f$ is the minimal polynomial for $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

The specific basis $\{ \theta^i \}$ would be called a *power basis*.

Comment: I was aware of the terminology "power basis" so I guess this is more standard. I'm good with the term equation order.